# haproxy redirect URL path to another path

Tags: redirect, haproxy, path

haproxy version 1.5.18

I want to redirect:

```
/document/(.*)/(.*)/somefile => /anotherPath/somefile
```

For example: redirect

```
/document/20181/20182/a_good_pic.jpg => /anotherPath/a_good_pic.jpg
```

How to do that with haproxy?

I retried follow the example for reqirep like:

```
# replace "/static/" with "/" at the beginning of any request path.
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /static/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

But my example has two parts in URL path that are different to the example, so I got confused.

Thanks!

Comment: This is much easier in HAProxy 1.6 and later, where you have access to features like [`http-request set-path`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-http-request) and a converter called [`regsub`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub). Also you are using the word *redirect* but you don't appear to actually want a redirect -- sending the browser the browser to a new URL with an HTTP `30X` response.  Do you want a redirect?  Or do you want to *rewrite the request* before sending it to the back-end?

Comment: Thanks. I will try HAProxy 1.6, if the IT people could upgrade it. Actually we don't care if it is a redirect or rewrite, as long as the last URL works for the user to download the required files.